# Newbie trying to create a gyroid sphere (gyroid ball) like this one

Tags: mathematics

I would like to create an object closely resembling this minimal surface gyroid intersecting a sphere, sometimes called a "gyroid sphere" or a "gyroid ball":

[image: Gyroid Ball by Dizingof]

Unfortunately the designer only offers the STL file [on his site](https://www.3dizingof.com/shop/math-art/gyroid-ball/). I don't plan to 3D print my object. I need the 3D file for further deformation, animation and reuse in a scene.

Edit:
Thanks to ZargulTheWizard 's reply I imported it and got this 550000 faces object that I now need to convert into a solid and animate deformations.

[image: Result after importing STL file]

Edit2:
As suggested I will decimate the number of faces to a more acceptable level (?). I realize now that Blender does not support solids (volumes) so if I cut my object I will have to "heal" the open ends. Same with Boolean ops.

My goal is to distort/warp continuously the resulting object (at the same time as scaling and rotating it globally as a whole) and to animate the result by varying the parameters involved as a function of time.

Question: if I want to distort, warp, twist the mesh what is the proper modifier to do so. Let's say I want to apply a mathematical transform to my geometry.

Comment: You can import STL with blender and it will be a regular mesh.

Comment: Thank you ZargulTheWizard! It worked nicely! I now have this object with more than 550000 faces. I need to convert it to a solid object and deform it. Is it possible within Blender?

Comment: Probably yes. How do you want it to deform? PS: 550K is kinda high, but you might be able to decimate it or something to lighten it down a little. (Ur welcome BJ, BTW)

Comment: How do you mean “make it solid?”

Comment: There is still no clear information as to what your *specific* intentions are with your question. How do you plan to animate this? What do you mean by solid? (Blender does not have solid objects, they are always hollow).. Please [edit] your question and clarify these things.

Comment: Remember, newbie here :) I now understand that Blender does not support solids, just surfaces. Also: I will decimate my mesh. I'm trying to figure out what kind(s) of transformation(s) (math or other) I can use to deform my object. I thought some of the modifiers like 'warp" would do the job. Was not able to make it work yet. I'm interested in modifiers similar to "twist" in 3DS Max: https://youtube.com/watch?v=bpPTb9f-l94 –